# Не могу решить задачу сохранения файла

Tags: swift

Проблема - не могу решить задачу сохранения файла - не работает Save Image, при нажатии на неё приложение вырубается и телефон временно зависает, а также не могу убрать вфункциональынй вывод кнопки Save Image

Более подробно обо всём:

У меня стоит задача в фотоальбомах или в новости, где есть основное фото - сохранение этого фото

Я не нашёл решения сохранения файла (фото, музыкального файла), но есть функционал шаринга

вызываю action кнопкой button (outlet) 
в нём вызываю метод UIActivityViewController

при исполнении этого метода вызывается алерт, принскрин прикрепляю

Внешний файл:

```
@IBAction func shareImageButton(_ sender: Any) {

    let url = URL(string: url_to_image)!
    let myImage = detailImageView.af_setImage(withURL: url)

    let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [detailImage], applicationActivities: nil)
    activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
    activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityType.postToFacebook,UIActivityType.postToTwitter]
    self.present(activityVC, animated:true, completion: nil)
```

}

или внутренний файл с текстом с немного другой организацией кода:

```
@IBAction func shareImageButton(_ sender: Any) {

    let imageToShare = UIImage(named: "User")
    self.myshare(shareText: "Sharing this text", shareImage: imageToShare)
```

}

```
func myshare(shareText shareText:String?,shareImage:UIImage?){

    var objectsToShare = [AnyObject]()

    if let shareTextObj = shareText{
        objectsToShare.append(shareTextObj as AnyObject)
    }

    if let shareImageObj = shareImage{
        objectsToShare.append(shareImageObj)
    }

    if shareText != nil || shareImage != nil{
        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
        activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view

        present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }else{
        print("There is nothing to share")
    }
}
```

Отправляется нормально или расшаривается картинка в Messager, facebook, Message, iCloud, работает Copy

Но есть справа внизу кнопка (смотри прикреплённый файл) - Save Image - при нажатии на неё приложение вырубается, телефон или эмулятор временно зависают

я пробовал подбирать свойства

activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [ UIActivityType.airDrop, UIActivityType.postToFacebook ]

Они не влияют на вывод SAve Image

Кстати, Save Image выводится когда подключаю именно картинку

let image = UIImage(named: "slide2")
let imageToShare = [ image! ]

Вопрос:
Как сделать так, что бы Работал Save Image или можно как-то Save Image в алерте вообще не выводить?
Куда именно сохраняется картинка при нажатии Save Image?

Comment: Приложите стектрейс ошибки

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался...
Info.plist

```
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Photo Library Access Warning</string>
```